# No route matches {:action=>"bands", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

When a user signs up for my site, they are redirected to '/welcome', which includes these links:

```
<%= link_to "Create Band Page", bands_user_path %>
<%= link_to "Complete Profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

The 'Complete Profile' link shows up and works fine.  However, the page won't display with the 'Create Band Page' link, and results in this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"bands", :controller=>"users"}
```

I have that link on the user's page and it works fine tho.

My users_controller includes this bit:

```
def bands
  @band = current_user.bands.build
  @bands = current_user.bands.all
  @user = current_user
end
```

And the relevant routes.rb parts look like this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers, :bands
  end
end
match '/welcome', to: 'static_pages#welcome'
```

As I said before, when I use the link on a user's show page it works fine, and rake routes includes the appropriate link:

```
bands_user GET    /users/:id/bands(.:format)      users#bands
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing it the user you want to display bands of.

Your route matches `/users/:id/bands(.:format)`. The format is an optional segment (that's what the parentheses mean), but `:id` is required. It expects you to pass in a valid user_id or user object to inflect a user_id from.

Try `<%= link_to "Create Band Page", bands_user_path(current_user) %>` and it should work.